# Restar 2 Fechas en JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

De antemano gracias por la ayuda
estoy trabajando en un formulario con 2 input tipo date, donde selecciono una fecha inicial, y fecha final, y queria obtener la diferencia en dias de ambas fechas, y que lo coloque en otro input por medio de Javascript

```
var FechaInicial =  ("#nuevaFechaInicial");

var FehcaRegreso = ("#nuevaFechaFinal");

var diferencia = Math.abs(FechaInicial.getTime()-FehcaRegreso.getTime());

    $("#diferencia ").val(diferencia);
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que fechaInicial es mayor a fechaFinal...

```
Math.ceil(diferencia / 86400000) // Cantidad de dias de diferencia.
```

Donde **86400000** es la cantidad de milisegundos en un dia, y

> diferencia

es la cantidad de milisegundos que hay entre ambas fechas.